# Java Converting String into Integer for Comparison

Tags: java, string, methods, interface, integer

I am writing a `compareTo` method for the Comparable Interface for a specific class. I need to take two different strings and compare them and see if one holds a greater value than the other. I would normally use `.compareTo()` but in this case it is giving me an error and not working. 
This is what I have:

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if (name < ((AccountOwnerComparable) o).name)
        return -1;
    else if (name > ((AccountOwnerComparable) o).name)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;

}
```

I know I can't use the `< or >` but it is just to show what the scenario is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have missed a bracket or something while casting. Try the following piece of code.

```
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    if (name.compareTo(((AccountOwnerComparable) o).name) > 0) {
        System.out.println("Greater");
        return -1;
    } else if (name.compareTo(((AccountOwnerComparable) o).name) < 0) {
        System.out.println("Lesser");
        return 1;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Equal");
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do:

```
name.compareTo(String_to_be_compare);
```

[compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29)

**public int compareTo(Object o)**

> Compares this String to another Object. If the Object is a String,
>   this function behaves like compareTo(String).

Note that:

**Returns**:

> The **value 0** if the argument is a **string lexicographically equal** to
>   this string; a value **less than 0** if the argument is a string
>   **lexicographically greater** than this string; and a value **greater than 0**
>   if the argument is a **string lexicographically less** than this string. ([source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo%28java.lang.Object%29))

So to your case:

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
{
    AccountOwnerComparable obj = (AccountOwnerComparable) o;
    return obj.name.compareTo(this.name);
}
```

tw: implement the comparable interface specifying what you want to compare to (usually the same type), since you did not specify anything your interface compares to anything which is odd.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface is *generic*. Your class declaration should probably look something like this:

```
class AccountOwnerComparable implements Comparable<AccountOwnerComparable> {...
```

Notice the `AccountOwnerComparable` type parameter. With this, you would have

```
public int compareTo(AccountOwnerComparable other) {
    return name.compareTo(other.name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Integer.parseInt()` method. In this way you could use `>` or `<` and it is more verbose.
I assume you want to compare two `String` objects containing numbers. Although you did not write it in the questions, the title says so.

Comment: They are not  `Integers`/. Both are `Strings` just containing letters. The `compareTo()` method returns an integer when it compares two different `Strings`. That is what I need

Comment: well, the title was misleading.